# [ink!]How to make cross contract calls with user defined parameters?

Tags: ink

I want to build a *delegator contract* to an **deployed** *callee contract* without knowing the source code details of the *callee contract*.

Related part of my *delegator contract* is as below:

```
#[ink(message)]
        pub fn call_to_contracts(&self, callee_account: AccountId, msg: ink_prelude::string::String) -> ink_prelude::string::String{
            
            let my_return_value: ink_prelude::string::String =  ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call_type(
                    ink_env::call::Call::new()
                        .callee(callee_account)
                        .gas_limit(0)
                        .transferred_value(0))
                .exec_input(
                    ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([0xa9, 0x45, 0xce, 0xc7]))
                    .push_arg(msg.into_bytes())
                )
                .returns::<ink_prelude::string::String>()
                .fire()
                .unwrap();
            my_return_value
        }
```

Related part of my *callee contract* is as below:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(::scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub struct MessageDetail{
        name: ink_prelude::string::String,
        age: u32,
        phones: ink_prelude::vec::Vec<ink_prelude::string::String>,
    }

/// test cross contract call
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn encode_user_defined_struct(&self, msg: MessageDetail) -> ink_prelude::string::String{
            ink_prelude::format!("{:?}", msg)
        }
```

First, I use [ContractUI](https://paritytech.github.io/contracts-ui) to make a test. I have tried the following input of the parameter `msg` when calling `call_to_contracts`:

- `{{\"name\":\"nika\",\"age\":18,\"phones\":[\"hello\",\"nika\"]}}`
- `{\"name\":\"nika\",\"age\":18,\"phones\":[\"hello\",\"nika\"]}`
- `{"name":"nika","age":18,"phones":["hello","nika"]}`

Besides, I have tried to replace the `.push_arg(msg.into_bytes())` with `.push_arg(msg)`.

But it's not working, I cannot see any error messages through *ContractUI*.

I'm sure if I defined the same `MessageDetail` in *delegator contract*, and change the parameter `msg` from `String` to `MessageDetail`, everything's OK.

But my purpose is to build a general delegator contract **without** knowing the source code details of the **callee**, is there any way I can try in `ink!`?

Comment: Have you checked out the [delegator example](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/delegator)?

Comment: I think it's not suitable for my situation. I think the `delegator example` is suitable for 'static' scenarios. But anyway, I have solved the problem. Thank you all the same.

Comment: You can post an answer and accept it yourself it this case.

Comment: Can you share the solution, I am stuck in same situation

Comment: It's a long time to be back here~ OK, I will share my solution below~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is encoding the user-defined struct in off-chain node.js, it will be like this:

```
...
/// encode user-defined data with ink api.
/// the `{"name": "Nika", "age": 18, "phones": ["123", "456"]}, "someone", 666` is user-defined parameters, there're three here
const calleeEncode = calleeABI.findMessage('encode_user_multi_params').toU8a([{"name": "Nika", "age": 18, "phones": ["123", "456"]}, "someone", 666]);

// it cannot be used until now, we should make more encoding manually
let ecdStr = '0x';
for (let i = 1; i < calleeEncode.length; ++i){
  let stemp = calleeEncode[i].toString(16);
  if (stemp.length < 2){
    stemp = '0' + stemp;
  }
  ecdStr += stemp;
}

...
/// Next, we can call *delegator contract* to make a delegate call to any callee contract.
/// the `contract` is the *delegator contract* instance
/// the `callToContracts` is the proxy call method
/// `5CgMjHnZm7VAi8x9HrB4b8FXYytnUj1pqNUH92yUmY9A7g8C` is the callee contract address
/// `ecdStr` is the encoded parameters and related method selector of the user-defined *callee contract*
const { gasConsumed, result, output } = await contract.query['callToContracts'](sender.address, {value, gasLimit }, 
                                       "5CgMjHnZm7VAi8x9HrB4b8FXYytnUj1pqNUH92yUmY9A7g8C", ecdStr);
```

The second thing is the related *delegator contract* method

```
...
/// because in our case we have more than one parameters for callee, so we need a `Wrapper` manually:
 struct Wrapper {
        data: ink_prelude::vec::Vec::<u8>,
    }
    
    impl Wrapper {
        pub fn new(data: ink_prelude::vec::Vec::<u8>) -> Self {
            Self {
                data,
            }
        }
    }
    
    impl scale::Encode for Wrapper {
        #[inline]
        fn size_hint(&self) -> usize {
            scale::Encode::size_hint(&self.data)
        }
    
        #[inline]
        fn encode_to<O: scale::Output + ?Sized>(&self, output: &mut O) {
            output.write(&self.data);
        }
    }

...
/// this is the delegate call
fn call_to_contracts(& self, callee_account: AccountId, msg: ink_prelude::vec::Vec::<u8>) -> ink_prelude::string::String{
            let data: ink_prelude::vec::Vec::<u8> = msg.clone().drain(4..).collect();
            let wrapped_data = Wrapper::new(data);
            
            let my_return_value: ink_prelude::string::String =  ink_env::call::build_call::<ink_env::DefaultEnvironment>()
                .call_type(
                    ink_env::call::Call::new()
                        .callee(callee_account)
                        .gas_limit(0)
                        .transferred_value(0))
                .exec_input(
                    ink_env::call::ExecutionInput::new(ink_env::call::Selector::new([msg[0], msg[1], msg[2], msg[3]]))
                    .push_arg(wrapped_data)
                )
                .returns::<ink_prelude::string::String>()
                .fire()
                .unwrap();
            my_return_value
        }
...
```